¿Cómo consigo que al cambiar de fondo de pantalla de forma automática, se consiga con un efecto de fade?
He hecho un script en Bash para automatizar el cambio de fondo de pantalla con la herramienta Nitrogen. Ahora bien, estoy buscando una forma de agregarle un desvanecido suave cada vez que cambie de imagen, pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo o que herramienta se puede combinar para ello. Dejo el código aquí:
#!/bin/bash

WALLPAPER_DIR="$HOME/Escritorio/wallpapers"
INTERVAL=20s #ejemplo

while true; do
    WALLPAPER =$(find "$WALLPAPER_DIR" -type f \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.png" \) | shuf -n 1)
    nitrogen --set-scaled "$WALLPAPER" 2> /dev/null
    sleep $INTERVAL
done




Prueba con las herramientas feh FEH y xcompmgr XCOMPMGR. Hace bastante que no las uso no se si te funcionará con Nitrogen.
#!/bin/bash

WALLPAPER_DIR="$HOME/Escritorio/wallpapers"
INTERVAL=20s #ejemplo

#Inicias xcomp
xcompmgr -c -t-5 -l-5 -r4.2 -o.55 &

while true; do
    WALLPAPER=$(find "$WALLPAPER_DIR" -type f \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.png" \) | shuf -n 1)
#Seleccionas en feh los aarchivos en este caso lso que guardas en $wallpaper
    feh --bg-scale "$WALLPAPER"
    sleep $INTERVAL
done


